# С какими параметрами надо генерировать ssl сертификат чтобы chrome последней версии на него не ругался?

Tags: openssl

Ключ создаю так

```
openssl req \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-x509 \
-nodes \
-keyout server.key \
-new \
-out server.crt \
-subj /CN=88.88.88.88 \
-reqexts SAN \
-extensions SAN \
-config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:88.88.88.88')) \
-sha256 \
-days 3650
```

сертификат создается апачи на него не ругается.
Браузер сертификат получает я его добавляю в доверенные.
Но хром не в какую не хочет назвать его надежным.
В инструменте разработчика пишет ошибку: 
Certificate error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

Вопрос что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: IP Внешний проброшен через роутер на локальный пк

Answer (score 0):

Вот что значит невнимательность =)

```
openssl req \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -x509 \
    -nodes \
    -keyout server.key \
    -new \
    -out server.crt \
    -subj /CN=88.88.88.88 \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -extensions SAN \
    -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
        <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=IP:88.88.88.88')) \
    -sha256 \
    -days 3650
```

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю это т.н. "самоподписанный сертификат". На него хром будет ругаться, т.к. нет оснований ему доверять. Его можно добавить в доверенные сертификаты, но в этом случае не будет ругаться только тот хром, который заставили ему сертификату доверять.

Если это необходимо для локальной отладки, то можно пойти и вышеописаным путем, а если для широких масс, то рекомендую обратить внимание на проект [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Моя процедура добавления поля SAN в запрос. Выполнял на debian 9.

- Копирую конфиг ssl.

  `$ sudo cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl-san.cnf`
- Добавляю в конец файла /etc/ssl/openssl-san.cnf строки.

  `[ san_env ]
  subjectAltName=${ENV::SAN}`
- Вставляю в переменную имя сервера.

  `$ export SAN=DNS:web-server.example.com`
- Формирую запрос.

  `$ openssl req -config /etc/ssl/openssl-san.cnf -reqexts san_env -new -key server.key -out web-server.example.com.req`
- Проверяю содержимое запроса.

  `$ openssl req -in web-server.example.com.req -text -noout | grep Alt
  X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:`
- Далее запрос отправляется в CA.